# eliminate drag select in wx.Grid

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to figure out how to eliminate drag behavior that is the default in a wx.Grid. I would like to end up with a grid for which the user cannot drag at all.

I (eventually) found MouseEventsManager, which looked ideal but doesn't do what I expect:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

class GridMouseEventsManager(wx.MouseEventsManager):
    def MouseDragBegin(self, item, pos):
        return False

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Sample grid")

        self.grid = gridlib.Grid(self)
        self.grid.CreateGrid(5,4)
        self.grid.SetCellSize(4,1,1,2)

        self.grid.SetColLabelSize(0)            # eliminates spreadsheet-style row & col headers
        self.grid.SetRowLabelSize(0)

        rowHeight = 50
        colWidth  = 50
        for i in range(1,5):
            self.grid.SetRowSize(i, rowHeight)
        for i in range(0,4):
            self.grid.SetColSize(i, colWidth)

        self.grid.SetCellBackgroundColour(4, 3, wx.LIGHT_GREY)

        # self.grid.SetCellHighlightPenWidth(0)   # eliminates highlighted cell, i.e., 'current' cell in spreadsheet
        self.grid.EnableCellEditControl(False)
        self.grid.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_SELECT_CELL, self.GridSelect, self.grid)

        self.grid_mouse_events_manager = GridMouseEventsManager(self.grid)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_exit)

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainSizer.Add(self.grid, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.selectedRow = -1
        self.selectedCol = -1

        self.SetSizerAndFit(mainSizer)
        # self.ShowFullScreen(True)

    def GridSelect(self, event):

        col = event.GetCol()
        row = event.GetRow()

        penWidth = 0
        if col == 1:
            penWidth = 2

        self.grid.SetCellHighlightPenWidth(penWidth)

        self.Refresh()

    def on_exit(self, event):
        self.grid_mouse_events_manager.Destroy()
        self.Destroy()

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This still has the default behavior, which is to select multiple cells when the user clicks and drags. I would like to disable dragging and/or multiple cell selection entirely.

I'm fairly new to Python, and even newer to wxPython; I haven't been able to find an explanation or example of how to do this. I tried the MouseEventsManager constructor with both the `self` object and with the `grid` object, neither of which seem to have any effect.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

Well, wouldn't you know that one more search on wxpython.org produced what I wanted

```
self.grid.GetGridWindow().Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMotion)

...

def OnMotion(self, event)
    # just trap this event and prevent it from percolating up the window hierarchy
    pass
```

That did what I want.